# C++ Weird Diamond inheritance issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, diamond-problem

I have this

```
    A
  /   \
 B     C
  \   /
    D
```

A has a pure virtual function, prototyped as:

```
virtual A* clone(void) const = 0;
```

B and C virtually inherit from A ( `class B: public virtual A`, `class C: public virtual A`)

B has the virtual function, prototyped as:

```
virtual B* clone(void) const {};
```

C has the virtual function, prototyped as:

```
virtual C* clone(void) const {};
```

D inherits from both B & C like that: `class D: public B, public C`
D has the virtual function, prototyped as:

```
virtual D* clone(void) const {};
```

Now, when compiling I get the following 6 lines of errors:

```
error C2250: 'D' : ambiguous inheritance of 'B *A::clone(void) const'
```

No freaking idea how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I get the following 6 lines of errors:" You missed the other 5.

Comment: I meant, I get the exact same error another 5 times...

Comment: Oh, I forgot how weird C++ compiler errors could be...

Comment: Did you notice the workaround I mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avoid diamond inheritance? ;->

anyway, here is sample (really sample - don't cast like that)

// ConsoleCppTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"

class A {
public:
    virtual void* clone() = 0;
};

class B: public A {
public:
    virtual void* clone() = 0;
};

class C: public A {
    public:
    virtual void* clone() = 0;
};

class D: public B, public C
{
public:


    virtual void* B::clone() 
    {
        std::cout << "B";
        return (void*)this;
    }

    virtual void* C::clone()
    {
        std::cout << "C";
        return (void*)this;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    D* d = new D();

    void* b = ((B*)d)->clone();

    void* c = ((C*)d)->clone();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function names in class `D` definition are flat out illegal. What is that supposed to mean: `B::clone`, `C::clone` in `D`?

Comment: @AndreyT I compiled it, ant it works - output is BC - that isn't pretty but diamond inheritance isn't pretty.

Comment: Well, I don't know what kind of compiler you are using, but the above code is not C++. In C++ you can't use qualified names (like `B::clone`) when declaring a function in a class.

Comment: @Andrey: MSVC++2010 allows this.  g++ errors, saying "cannot define member function `B::clone` within `D`"

Comment: @AndreyT: exactly - and questions has tag 'visual-2010' so for me is correct - ugly but correct  your anserw is much prettier

Answer (score 9):

Use virtual inheritance if you want only one copy of a parent in your hierarchy.

```
class B : public virtual A
```

**Edit:**
There may be a bug in MSVC++ 2010.  The Intellisense doesn't detect a problem, but the compiler chokes on it.  Strange since VC6 is happy enough with it.

As a workaround, if you declare D as follows, it makes MSVC++ 2010 happy while also working in compilers without this issue:

```
class D: public virtual A, public B, public C
```

Comment: IntelliSense sees no problem with the code because The Visual C++ 2010 IntelliSense uses the EDG frontend, not the Visual C++ frontend.  I stripped down @AndreyT's example to the minim required to reproduce the problem and reported a bug:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/590625/visual-c-incorrectly-reports-ambiguity-when-covariance-is-used-with-virtual-inheritance.

Answer (score 5):

What you describe in your original post is perfectly legal. A quick sample code that does exactly that compiles without any errors by Comeau Online compiler

```
class A {
public: virtual A* clone() const = 0;
};

class B: public virtual A {
public: virtual B* clone() const { return 0; }
};

class C: public virtual A {
public: virtual C* clone() const { return 0; }
};

class D: public B, public C
{
public: virtual D* clone() const { return 0; }
};
```

Either you are not doing what you said you are doing, or your compiler is broken. Post real code you are trying to compile.

**P.S.** I just tried compiling this in VS 2010 Express and got the same error. As Gunslinger47 also suggests in the comments, this is a bug in VS 2010 compiler.

Comment: Looks like an issue with MSVC++2010.